# How to make fast layout in symfony?

Tags: jquery, layout, symfony1, performance

I made a site in Symfony, and my layout contains a lot of jquery code, with lot of
slider plugins (Anythingslider, jqfancytransitions). When I load my page, it's very slow because of these things. It won't be problem, if the layout would be loaded once, but naturally it's loading all the times, when I click another link. So, I've read about caching, but in this case that would't work. So, could you give a solution for my problem?

Comment: Well... could you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

If your slowness is due to your javascript-loaded template, caching it won't suffice. Look at symfony's timers in the web debug bar, because the slowness might come **after** the page has been rendered by symfony: it may slow down the client side rendering because of all the work related to javascript that the browser has to do.

Try reducing the amount of JS calls or maybe delaying them until they are absolutely necessary - that should speed up page load time.

Comment: Also check out [Google's page speed tools](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/extension.html) for benchmarking the client-side performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked the Page Speed tool, it's very cool! Meanwhile I found a good solution for my speed problem. A load the whole page (with the slow layout) only once at the beginning, after I always refresh the content via Ajax. (I use the remote_function function)